# tab strip in telerik grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

In  my mvc web application, I am using telerik tab strip for different tabs.
Now I want that for each tab , I can call different action method of controller.
How Can I do that?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to post the data only the current tab, you can create a form on each tab, each with its action. If need to post data from the entire page you can manipulate the action of form with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what your requirement is but I will tell what the tabstrip can do.

If you want the tabstrip to invoke an action method after clicking a tab use the Action method of the fluent API to specify it:

```
tabs.Add().Text("Home").Action("Index" /* action */, "Home" /* controller */);
```

If you want to specify an action whose output (view) is loaded in the tab use the LoadContentFrom method:

```
tabs.Add().Text("Home").LoadContentFrom("Index" /* action */, "Home" /* controller */);
```

You can check the [ajax load on demand demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/tabstrip/ajaxloading) for a live example of the second.